# Android Studio keeps building old version

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

it's been ages since I updated my app to the Play Store so possibly I'm skipping something simple but I've updated my code and my build gradle

```
    versionCode 15 //increased from v 14
    versionName "1.34" // increased from 1.33
```

But whenever it builds, it's building me a version from 27 September 2017 (possibly the last time I updated the app)

[Build 27/09/17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqjjd.png)

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding but I'm still getting the old version compiled.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Delete that apk and try again. If it doesn't reappear, then your apk is being put somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Squeeish, I updated everything and why I haven't responded sooner. Yes it's missing. Do you know where Android Studio stores these apk's by default? Having trouble locating it.

Comment: How are you building your apk? Through Build - Build APK(s)? If so, at the bottom right of Android Studio, click on Event Log. The location of the apk is shown there. Otherwise browse your app folder, normally under app/build. Also inspect your build.gradle file for clues.

Comment: I'm going to try an older version of Android Studio 2.33, which I think was used for my last update.

Comment: I'm not having any joy with this problem. It still keeps building me a version from 27/09/2017. I've tried deleting the build and rebuilding but it keeps giving me the old version.

Comment: Delete your build folder and try again. Clone the project on another computer and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent over two days trying out various solutions, but unfortunately, none of them worked. The only solution that worked for me was to delete the `android/.idea` folder and building the app again using Android Studio.